# Change Bootstrap's collapse button's value on click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have searched the forum, I have searched Google and read all the articles but I still can't seem to get this right. What I would like to do is to change my button's value on click. That is if the content is shown then I would like to change the value of the button to let's say "hide." And if the content is hidden, then the button should show its default value of "check."

My code:

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<td>One two</td>
<td><input type="text" id="input"></td>
<td>four five</td>
<td class="button"><button class="my-btn" type="button" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAnswer" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-controls="collapseAnswer" onclick="checkInput()">
CHECK
</button></td>
<td id="collapseAnswer">
<span id="message"></span>             
</td>
</tr>
</table>

function checkInput()
{
var a=document.getElementById("input");
if ((a.value=="three")||(a.value=="three"))
{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Correct!";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Wrong";
}
}
```

Here is a link to my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xd6vwLop/

But now it seems it doesn't work here... Although in my file it shows the innerHTML and hides it as well on a second click. I'd like to change the value of the button if the innerHTML is shown.

Is there also a possibility to speed up the animation when the innerHTML is supposed to disappear? It takes too much time and some users might want to click again on the button since it takes some time to hide the content.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the updated JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xrtmpy4f/

Basically, you need use the `innerText` property to change the text of the button

```
function checkInput() {
  var a=document.getElementById("input");
  var checkbtn = document.getElementById("check-btn");

  if (checkbtn.innerText.trim() === 'CHECK') {
    checkbtn.innerText = 'HIDE';
      if ((a.value=="three")||(a.value=="three")) {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Correct!";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Wrong";
   }
   return;
  }

  if (checkbtn.innerText.trim() === 'HIDE') {
    checkbtn.innerText = 'CHECK';
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '';
    return;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great! And the answer appears and hides instantly without this weird delay. 

Can I ask you something else too? Do you perhaps know how to implement keypress event to the input? I would like to press Enter and have the answer Correct/Wrong appear as if I clicked on the button without deleting the button. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I have used @vaishali's code to get what you wanted. Check the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I couldn't make your code to work in my file so I came up with this solution. I added onkyepress="myFunction()" to my input and then worked with @vaishali's code creating a function like this: 
    function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("input");
    elem.onkeypress =  function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) { 
            checkInput();
          }
      }
};

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkInput() {
  var text = document.getElementById("check-btn");
  text.innerText === 'CHECK' ? (text.innerText = 'HIDE') : (text.innerText = 'CHECK');
var a=document.getElementById("input");
if ((a.value=="three")||(a.value=="three"))
{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Correct!";
}
else
{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Wrong";
}
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to implement keypress event to the input? I would like to press Enter and have the answer Correct/Wrong appear as if I clicked on the button without deleting the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("input");
elem.onkeydown =  function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
       checkInput();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add it in the closure so that it doesn't override with other variables.

```
(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("input");
    elem.onkeydown =  function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //checks whether the pressed key is "Enter"
           checkInput();
        }
    }
})();
```